# How to fix the algorithm for table generation?

Tags: reactjs

I have an algorithm for generating a table of two arrays.

```
data = [mail, cat, dog]

words = [{postman, mailbox, letter}, {kitty, kitten, koshak, kotyara}, {dog, friend}]
```

The number of "subarrays" in the words array is always equal to the number of elements in the data array.

The data array is the column headings, and the "subarrays" of words must be columns.

My generation algorithm works fine, but the "subarrays" in my implementation are obtained as rows, and as I said, I need to have columns.

```
<Paper style={{ maxWidth: 936, margin: "auto" }}>
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        {data.map((TableRow, i) => (
                            <TableCell key={i} align="center">
                                {TableRow.split("_").join(" ")}
                            </TableCell>
                        ))}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {this.state.array.map((user, i) => (
                        <TableRow key={i}>
                            {Object.values(user).map((v, j) => (
                                <TableCell key={j} align="center">
                                    <IconButton>
                                        <AddIcon/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                    {v}
                                    <IconButton>
                                        <RemoveIcon/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                </TableCell>
                            ))}
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell align="center">
                            <Button variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                style={{
                                    background:
                                        "linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68 90%)"
                                }}
                            >Обучить
                            </Button>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>
```

Comment: Your `words` array should be transposed in the first place.

Comment: can u show screenshot table that is expected u want

Comment: Also, you should use arrays, not iterate over `Object.values`. `Object.values` is not guaranteed to return always the same order of elements.

Comment: @Sulthan order of elements doesnt really matter to me. How can I transpose it?

Comment: Your data should looks like this: `words = [ [postman, kitty, dog], [mailbox, kitten, friend], [letter, koshak, null], [null, kotyara, null] ]`. Then you will have no problem rendering the rows. Think about the way to convert the data to the given format.